# Run Google Analytics reports across multiple accounts / properties

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, multiple-domains

So I have a single login for Google Analytics that tracks multiple accounts with multiple properties as so.

Account 1

- Property A
- Property B
- Property C
- Property D

Account 2

- Property E
- Property F
- Property G

These sites are all separate and it's not a case that visitors will go to site A and then onto site B or anything like that. All sites are their own self-contained unit.

I would like to create a report that was able to give me stats across all these sites such as *browser usage*, *user locations* and such like. Any ideas how I could go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately you'll need to look into writing a Google Apps script for this. See https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/articles/reporting-apps-script for a good starting tutorial.

The process can seem somewhat daunting at first, but is incredibly powerful once you become comfortable working with the API.

Comment: I thought I would have to go down the coding route. Not really an issue but you're right, it is daunting! Thanks for the help :)

Comment: The code can be intimidating, but once you get into the world of Google Apps scripts, all kinds of awesomeness is readily available to you. Tying Analytics data with Webmaster Tools data, with AdWords data can produce some really valuable insights, as an example. And you can produce a pretty doc in a Google spreadsheet for a boss/client :)